# Elasticsearch to SQL equivalent, get the first and last documents with filter

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an issue with elasticsearch documents. So the goal is I need to get the latest data `close` from index `stocks` and also the last data `close` from `stocks` within a specified date. Here's the example of the SQL equivalent:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT `close` FROM `stocks` WHERE date >= 2022-06-01 ORDER by date DESC LIMIT 1
) as last_close, 
(
    SELECT `close` FROM `stocks` ORDER by date ASC LIMIT 1
) as latest_close FROM stocks
```

That's the goal I need to achieve, for the rest I think I don't need to share because the bottleneck is on that issue.
Edited: This is the mappings on my index `stocks` in elasticsearch:

```
{
  "stocks": { - 
    "mappings": { - 
      "properties": { - 
        "avg": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "board": { - 
          "type": "text"
        },
        "book": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "change": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "chg": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "close": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "date": { - 
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        },
        "der": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "eps": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "fve": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "fvei": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "group": { - 
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "high": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "low": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "open": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "paid_up_cap_shares": { - 
          "type": "text",
          "fields": { - 
            "keyword": { - 
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "pbv": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "peg_analysis": { - 
          "type": "text"
        },
        "peg_ratio": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "per": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "prev": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "roe": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "stock": { - 
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "trade_freq": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "trade_val": { - 
          "type": "double"
        },
        "trade_vol": { - 
          "type": "double"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the document example for the index:

```
{
    "_index": "stocks",
    "_id": "6odITIEBRQt2Zq4UUGu3",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "date": "2022-06-10 13:23:36",
        "fvei": "112833.74",
        "pbv": "0.0",
        "prev": "97",
        "book": "-1.185716459E8",
        "roe": "-7.87",
        "der": "-6.87",
        "high": "91",
        "avg": "91.0",
        "fve": "91.0",
        "low": "91",
        "stock": "WINR",
        "per": "0.0",
        "close": "91",
        "trade_vol": "46283600",
        "group": "IDXPROPERT",
        "paid_up_cap_shares": "0.1",
        "trade_val": "4211807600",
        "chg": "-6.59",
        "change": "-6.0",
        "peg_ratio": "0.0",
        "eps": "9327072.3",
        "trade_freq": "1433",
        "peg_analysis": "negative growth",
        "board": "RG",
        "open": "91"
    }
},
{
    "_index": "stocks",
    "_id": "7IdITIEBRQt2Zq4UUGu3",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "date": "2022-06-10 13:23:36",
        "fvei": "66215.12",
        "pbv": "0.0",
        "prev": "685",
        "book": "1946574.58",
        "roe": "22.08",
        "der": "3.62",
        "high": "685",
        "avg": "677.5",
        "fve": "680.0",
        "low": "670",
        "stock": "TLDN",
        "per": "0.0",
        "close": "680",
        "trade_vol": "577600",
        "group": "IDXNONCYC",
        "paid_up_cap_shares": "540.65",
        "trade_val": "393001500",
        "chg": "-0.73",
        "change": "-5.0",
        "peg_ratio": "0.0",
        "eps": "429847.27",
        "trade_freq": "117",
        "peg_analysis": "negative growth",
        "board": "RG",
        "open": "685"
    }
},
```

Comment: can you share your sample Elasticsearch doucments and its mapping ?

Comment: Already edited, the document and mapping

Comment: Can you share more sample documents and than the expected document from that list to better understand your requirement ?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't have any other example documents, especially the older data. but the main goal is I need to take "close" documents from the last and the first. for the last is there's a filter for specified date and sort by date descending, and for the first is take only the latest date.

Comment: Got it, now its much more clear to me, let me spend some time and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer by using top_hits:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    // range filter
                    "range": {
                        "date": {
                            "gte": "now-89d",
                            "lte": "now+1d"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "group": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "stock"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "last_doc": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "date": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "_source": {
                            "includes": ["close"]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "first_doc": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "date": {
                                    "order": "asc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "_source": {
                            "includes": ["close"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```